# Как создать динамически типизированную коллекцию?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Для примера коллекция -

```
class Collection {
    insert(node){

    }
    swap(a, b){
        // в этом методе я должен обращаться
        // к свойствам node.someProps
    }
}
```

А с генериками `.ts` это будет приблизительно так -

```
class Collection<T> {
    public insert<T>(node: T): void {

    }
    public swap<T>(a: T, b: T): void{
        // в этом методе я должен обращаться
        // к свойствам node.someProps

        // !!! НО !!!
    }
}
```

... НО я этого не могу, так как у типа `T` нет свойства `someProps`.
Вопрос - как сделать динамическую коллекцию с базовым типом, который будет иметь нужные свойства? да и возвращать хотелось бы конечный тип, а не базовый.

Вот пример на [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20BaseNode%20%7B%0A%09someProps%3A%20any%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Collection%3CBaseNode%3E%20%7B%0A%09swap%3CT%3E(a%3A%20BaseNode%2C%20b%3A%20BaseNode)%3A%20void%20%7B%0A%09%09let%20value%20%3D%20a.someProps%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%7D).

Comment: очевидно на ruSO эта метка не очень популярна :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как класс уже generic, не нужно указывать это для функций.

Для определения ограничений можно воспользоваться [примером из справки](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Generics.md#generic-constraints)

```
interface BaseNode {
    someProps: number;
}

class Collection<T extends BaseNode> {
    swap(a: T, b: T): void {
        let value = a.someProps; // T extends BaseNode, so have someProps
    }
}
```

[***Пример***](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20BaseNode%20%7B%0A%09someProps%3A%20any%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Collection%3CT%20extends%20BaseNode%3E%20%7B%0A%09swap(a%3A%20T%2C%20b%3A%20T)%3A%20void%20%7B%0A%09%09let%20value%20%3D%20a.someProps%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%7D)

Comment: Я тоже пока ждал решил еще раз попробовать с `extends` и на удивление со второго раза получилось :) Спасибо.

Comment: @IvanPetrov, обратите также внимание что у самой функции generic убран и используется определение типа из класса, если вернуть его в функцию `swap<T>` - то опять все сломается так как для типов функции extends не будет прописан

Comment: Да, да! Если генерик применить на методе, то приходится поновому прописывать `extends`.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно прописать [ограничение на тип `T`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Generics.md#generic-constraints):

```
interface BaseNode {
    someProps: any;
}

class Collection<T extends BaseNode> {
    swap(a: T, b: T): void {
        let value = a.someProps;
    }
}
```

Либо, если лишний интерфейс не хочется заводить:

```
class Collection<T extends { someProps: any; }> {
    swap(a: T, b: T): void {
        let value = a.someProps;
    }
}
```

Comment: не совсем верный пример получился, `T` нигде не используется, а в `BaseNode` это поле и так было доступно